# JavaScript EMV TLV Parser

Tags: javascript, emv

I am trying to parse the card data for EMV TLV transactions. Are there any parsers for decoding EMV TLV card data for JavaScript that do not use node.js?

Answer (score 1):

My favourite application that partially does this is [TVR Decoder](https://tvr-decoder.appspot.com/t/home). It actually does a little more than just decode TVR. [Its source code is on Github](https://github.com/wcurrie/emv-bertlv-tools) if you want to contribute to the project.

Alternatively, I also liked the EMV Data Viewer proprietary software from the Ingenico SDK. I strongly doubt it is coded in JS thought.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to read the specifications from the EMVCo page https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223

It depends on the exact command / response you want to decode.

Responses have different Tags which may occur in templates. You need to know what tag you have, and then using the template you would know exactly what is expected as value. The length always comes after the tag. The value itself can also be a TLV of a different Tag.

Check this video 
https://youtu.be/iWg8EBhsfjY
It explains how to decode using some examples responses.

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](https://www.openscdp.org/scripts/download.html) out. It has most of the things you do in emv processing. Can give you a better idea even if does not match your exact requirement. Quite understandable coding.

But I can say, a little effort, you can do it on your own.

- Get the list of mandatory and optional tags from EMVCo books.
- Get the length of the data which follows
- Get the data( note that some R-APDU come in templates, these details are also there in EMVCo books).